# How to get the number of alarms in Android phone?

Tags: java, android, android-alarms

I am trying to use the following code to get the number of alarms currently set on the phone.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.deskclock/AlarmClock");
Cursor c = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null,null);
```

But I get a `NullPointerException` when I try to fetch the number using

```
int num = c.getCount();
System.out.println("No of alarms : "+c.getCount());
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong ? The exception occurs in getCount() itself so I am not able to display the number of alarms.

**EDIT:** I also get this message on my LogCat :

```
ActivityThread(13290): Failed to find provider info for com.android.deskclock
```

Comment: All i have to display it is a println statement. But it won't even go there because exception occurs in the previous line. I have updated my post.

Comment: @NambiNarayanan: please check my edit. I also get that additional message.

Comment: Try with "content://com.android.deskclock/alarm" once

Comment: Not working. Same exception

Comment: Have you Already set any alarm before you are trying to get the number of alarms currently set on the phone.

Comment: yes I have.. I have gone to the alarm app on my phone and checked. It has 5 alarms, but it doesn't reflect through my code

Comment: Please again give a try with this snippet
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.alarmclock/alarm"); 
most probably it may return permission Denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Uri` you're looking for is `content://com.android.deskclock/alarms`, but you can't access the app's `ContentProvider` because it isn't exported. You'll just throw a `SecurityException`.

Comment: Are you saying the only way I can get this information is by **rooting** the phone?

Comment: No, but I suppose that's one way of doing it.

Comment: Any other way to do this?

Comment: Submit a patch to the AOSP and maybe it gets approved.