# How to get the number of alarms from the alarms db in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I need to get the number of alarms that have currently been set. I tried one approach, as illustrated here : [How to get the number of alarms in Android phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523404/how-to-get-the-number-of-alarms-in-android-phone?noredirect=1#comment34273714_22523404)

Can I do this by reading the alarms database? Can someone please post code showing me how to do the same?

Any other solution will also be appreciated.

Comment: Lol.. that is also my post and the link I posted in this question. Hahaha!!

Comment: In fact, by using the ContentProvider, you probably read the database containing the alarms. ContentProvider is just a convenience facade for you. But it is not intended for use by other applications (because as **adneal** mentioned, it is not exported), so you fail using this ContentProvider. From your app you cannot directly access another app's database, as it's permissions restrict you from doing so. So, there's nothing to do with it, I guess - consider this "feature" as a design flaw of Android Alarm app.

Comment: By the way, even if your phone is rooted, it is not necessary that your app will succed reading another app's database. By default, app runs as an unprivileged user, not as root. Possibly, you'd have to use some other magic in order to fetch a db on the rooted phone. Is it really worth playing? :)

Comment: @Drew: I wish I had a choice on the matter :D

Comment: @Gautham Modify source and compile, maybe? :) But it would be nothing more than educational experiment. I really think the AOSP alarm app is not widespread, and not every phone running Android has it on board - my does not.