# Is rooting a requirement for reading the database files such as alarm.db?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, root, android-alarms

I would like to know if **rooting** is a requirement to read the database files such as **alarms.db** from my app ? If not, then how should I proceed to do the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523404/how-to-get-the-number-of-alarms-in-android-phone

Comment: That is my post :) I posted this only after failing at that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course yes.
I often do this for some reasons.But if your phone is not rooted,these files are not allowed for reading or writing.
When you have rooted your phone,you can take the su permission to remount the file system or change the mode of the file so that it can be read.